# nfs issue on AWS Amazon Linux2

Tags: amazon-ec2, nfs, nfsclient

I'm running multiple websites on Amazon AWS. I mounted and EBS on the master server, the mount dir hold the website's files.

Also, I configured the application load balancer, which installs small instances when there is a load on the master. The clone servers running NFS clients to connect to the master server and mount the website's files.

Everything works perfectly, but the issue many times the clones server cannot mount the NFS server even when I try to mount manually. I have to run `exportfs -f` to flush the NFS table on the master instance.

I do not know why this happens. If you need any further information just give the CMD for it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand You are trying to mount the EBS from multiple ec2 instances.
This can be done using the multi-attach capability of EBS. However the are some limitations to this capability (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html). So, in short, if You have more than 16 instanced trying to mount to this EBS, you hit the limit.

My suggestion to solve that - Use EFS instead. EFS is an elastic file system managed service by AWS. Really simple to use, can be mounted from multiple Linux instances and elastic (so you pay-as-you-grow). Check it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-multiple-ec2-instances.html